# Need help in creating ' Guesing Game ' in Kotlin. Unable to check for previous input number and match it with current input number

Tags: kotlin, if-statement

I hope you all hear about ' Guessing Game '. The user has to guess a number and then the match goes on with generated Random number.
Now, I have written code for this, but there is a glitch and that is I am unable to understand how to write the condition for -> count variable not getting increased by 1 if just previous input number is same as the current input number by the user.

I am putting my code here:

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.random.Random.Default.nextInt

fun main() {

    val randomNumber = (1..100).random()
    println(randomNumber)
    var count: Int = 0
    
    while (true){
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var inputNumber: Int = reader.nextInt()
    println("input number: $inputNumber")


    if (randomNumber == inputNumber) {
        println("You guessed it correct")
        count += 1
        print("You took $count guesses")
        break
    } else if (randomNumber > inputNumber) {
        println("You guessed it too small")
    } else {
        println("You guessed it too large")
    }
    count += 1
    print("Guess count: $count")


}
```

**Desired output:**

input number: 12 
You guessed it too small 
Guess count: 1

input number: 25 
You guessed it too large 
Guess count: 2

input number: 25 
You guessed it too large 
Guess count: 2

input number: 20 
You guessed it right 
Guess count: 3

**My output:**

input number: 12 
You guessed it too small 
Guess count: 1

input number: 25 
You guessed it too large 
Guess count: 2

input number: 25 
You guessed it too large 
Guess count: 3

input number: 20 
You guessed it right 
Guess count: 4

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you show your desired input and output, and explain how that is different from the actual output of your code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Edited. Please read it as ' input number' and then ' String ' and then ' Guess count '.

Comment: What if I guessed 12, then 25, then 12 again? Should the guess count be 3 or 2?

Comment: No then it should be 3. Condition is for two consecutive similar inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a variable for tracking the previous input. It should have an initial value of null so it's not possible to accidentally have it tell you your first guess is a repeated one. Before adding to the count, check for the repeated value and `continue` the loop if it's a repeat.  I'd also put the `count += 1` before you check whether the guess is correct so it doesn't have to appear in two places in your code. I also moved the creation of the Scanner before the loop so you aren't redundantly recreating it each time it's used.

```
fun main() {
    val randomNumber = (1..100).random()
    println(randomNumber)
    var count: Int = 0
    var previousInput: Int? = null
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)

    while (true) {
        val inputNumber: Int = reader.nextInt()
        if (inputNumber == previousInput) {
            println("That is the same as your previous guess.")
            continue
        }
        count += 1
        previousInput = inputNumber

        if (randomNumber == inputNumber) {
            println("You guessed it correct")
            print("You took $count guesses")
            break
        } else if (randomNumber > inputNumber) {
            println("You guessed it too small")
        } else {
            println("You guessed it too large")
        }
        println("You've taken $count guess(es)")
    }
}
```